# Check Constraint SQL in MariaDB

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb, constraints

according to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/ MariaDB now supports CHECK constraints.
When I run this SQL command:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a INT CHECK (a>2), 
                 b INT CHECK (b>2), 
                 CONSTRAINT a_greater CHECK (a>b)
);
```

I get the following error:

[image]

So, if CHECK keyword is just after the field, is accepted.
If I try to add a constraint in a separate row, it doesn't work.
Please note that the command I am trying to run is exactly the one suggested by mariadb.com itself.

Why is the first one accepted and is the second one rejected?

My DBMS is MariaDB 10.4.11

Comment: It looks like those errors are coming from the IDE, not the database. Are you sure you configured it to use MariaDB 10.4 syntax?

Comment: You were right. I have run the query even with that error, and it works. Now I would like to configure it to use MariaDB 10.4 syntax, but I don't know how

Comment: What is the IDE? Usually in the settings there's a place where you can specify all the language versions.

Comment: phpMyAdmin (through XAMPP)

Comment: I can't find anything about this in the PhpMyAdmin documentation.

Comment: Make sure it's up to date.

Comment: Check [Add support for CHECK constraints (feature request) #13592](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/13592).

Comment: @wchiquito's comment is the best (and probably should be posted as the answer here); this is currently a bug (or enhancement, technically) with the language parser used by phpMyAdmin. Right now, you can ignore the parser errors and run the SQL command manually. And phpMyAdmin automatically detects your database server and version, so you wouldn't have to configure it for MariaDB mode.

Comment: Your `CREATE` worked fine for me on 10.2.30 from the "mysql" commandline.  Please show us the syntax that fails.